# How to retrieve original @classmethod, @staticmethod or @property

Tags: python

I understand that @decorator.decorator doesn't allow to decorate above @staticmethod, @classmethod (and perhaps also @property). I understand the usage:

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    @mydecorator
    def my_method(cls): pass
```

But, in a debugging module, I still want to try to do it dynamically. So I was wondering what is the way to retrieve the original method from those descriptor(?). I've read few responses, but I'm still confused...

I see some example with a class, and retrieving:

```
class my_class(property):
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        return self.fget.__get__(None, cls)
```

I love the signature-preserving of decorator, but still not sure how to do this. The logic I try to implement is:

```
import decorator

def mydecorator(f, *d_args, **d_kwargs):
    if (isinstance(f, classmethod)):
        return classmethod(mydecorator(f.__get__.?WHATELSE?))
    elif (isinstance(f, staticmethod)):
        return staticmethod(mydecorator(f.__get__.?WHATELSE?))
    elif (isinstance(f, property)):
        return property(mydecorator(f.__get__.?WHATELSE?))
    else:
        return decorator.decorator(f)
```

I'm trying to do this in Python 2.6, so I also welcome pointing that @decorator is changed (corrected?) in future version of python.

Thanks.

Comment: if you are using `classmethod`, `property`and the like, it is __crucial__ that your classes inherit from the `object` base class. Otherwise, these things simply won't work, as they are designed to work in new style classes.

Comment: @jsbueno: Is the comment referring to the example `class my_class(property)`, or are you saying I cannot do it with a function, but have to do it with a `class` (descriptor?).

Comment: @Danosaure: Your `class A:` **must** be `class A(object):`

Comment: Danusaure - just as @Daenyth puts it. Do it.

Comment: Oh, I just changed in my OP, but if you can comment about my answer... I also started to put fget, fset and fdel, but didn't have time to play with it more for now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Considering:

```
>>> def original():pass

>>> classmethod(original).__func__ == original
True
>>> staticmethod(original).__func__ == original
True
>>> property(original).fget == original
True
```

Your function should be something like:

```
import decorator

def mydecorator(f, *d_args, **d_kwargs):
    if (isinstance(f, classmethod)):
        return classmethod(mydecorator(f.__func__))
    elif (isinstance(f, staticmethod)):
        return staticmethod(mydecorator(f.__func__))
    elif (isinstance(f, property)):
        return property(mydecorator(f.fget))
    else:
        return decorator.decorator(f)
```

**UPD:** Sorry for inattention. In 2.* prior to 2.7. , you should do something like:

```
import decorator
def mydecorator(f, *d_args, **d_kwargs):
    if (isinstance(f, classmethod)):
        return classmethod(mydecorator(f.__get__(True).im_func))
    elif (isinstance(f, staticmethod)):
        return staticmethod(mydecorator(f.__get__(True)))
    elif (isinstance(f, property)):
        return property(mydecorator(f.fget))
    else:
        return decorator.decorator(f)
```

Note that those `True` objects in `f.__get__(True).im_func` statement could be replaced by any object except `None`.

Comment: I get the error `AttributeError: 'classmethod' object has no attribute '__func__'`. Is this available in Python 2.6?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I think for static method, it should be `f.__get__(True)` (no need to get `im_func` which throws an error).

Comment: accepted as answer as it helped me straight to where I wanted to go.

Answer (score 1):

I am putting this back so it may be useful to anyone:

```
def redecorate(redecorator):
    def wrapper(f):
        info = (f, None)
        if (isinstance(f, classmethod)):
            info = (f.__get__(True).im_func, classmethod)
        elif (isinstance(f, staticmethod)):
            info = (f.__get__(True), staticmethod)
        elif (isinstance(f, property)):
            info = (f.fget, property)

        if (info[1] is not None):
            return info[1](redecorator(info[0]))
        return redecorator(info[0])
    return wrapper
```

Then, one would use it this way:

```
import decorator
@decorator.decorator
def my_decorator(f, *args, **kwargs):
    print "Pre-process..."
    try:
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    finally:
        print "Post-process..."

my_redecorator = redecorate(my_decorator)

@my_redecorator
def my_function(a): print "in my_function(a)"

class My_Class(object):
    @my_redecorator
    def my_method(self, a): print "in my_method(self, a)"

    @my_redecorator
    @classmethod
    def my_classmethod1(cls, a): print "in my_classmethod1(cls, a)"

    @classmethod
    @my_redecorator
    def my_classmethod2(cls, b): print "in my_classmethod2(cls, b)"

    @my_redecorator
    @staticmethod
    def my_staticmethod1(a): print "in my_staticmethod1(a)"

    @staticmethod
    @my_redecorator
    def my_staticmethod2(b): print "in my_staticmethod2(b)"

    @my_redecorator
    @property
    def my_property1(self): print "in my_property1(self)"

    @property
    @my_redecorator
    def my_property2(self): print "in my_property2(self)"
```

And now, if I call them:

```
my_function(1)

My_Class.my_classmethod1(1)
My_Class.my_classmethod2(1)

My_Class.my_staticmethod1(1)
My_Class.my_staticmethod2(2)

my_class = My_Class()

my_class.my_method(1)
my_class.my_property1
my_class.my_property2
```

The output will be:

```
Pre-process...
in my_function(a)
Post-process...
Pre-process...
in my_classmethod1(cls, a)
Post-process...
Pre-process...
in my_classmethod2(cls, b)
Post-process...
Pre-process...
in my_staticmethod1(a)
Post-process...
Pre-process...
in my_staticmethod2(b)
Post-process...
Pre-process...
in my_method(self, a)
Post-process...
Pre-process...
in my_property1(self)
Post-process...
Pre-process...
in my_property2(self)
Post-process...
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i'm doing it, is by attaching a list `_decorated` to the decorated function and am able to:

1. determine if the function is decorated
2. by which decorators in
3. which order.

```
def mydecorator(f):
    do_decoration()
    if hasattr(f, '_decorated'):
        f._decorated.append(decorator)
    else:
        f._decorated = [decorator]
    return f
```

Comment: I am not sure how this solve my problem. Can you give more explanation how I detect the original method that has `@classmethod`, `@staticmethod` and `@property` on them?

Comment: Sorry i didn't elaborate further: but in general if i know beforehand that i might want to preserve some information i adapt the decorator in such way, i can add the needed information at run-time. If i have to add functionality afterwards i once used an `inspect`-module approach by monitoring the stack-frame with `inspect.getouterframes`. Can't find the code anymore - but it was messy and i'm not sure if i would post it here! ;-)